# how to update datagridview to database using c#?

Tags: c#, datagridview, sql-update, tableadapter

I have a datagridview bound to a datasouce, bound to a datatable.
I want to create a button that when I click it, the database will be updated with the new parameters in the datagridview.
I've read some stuff about TableAdapter but I cant really find some good examples and explanations.

So if someone can give some information about tableadapter, it will help me a lot.
Also, if you think that you have a better solution for me regarding update the database, i'll be glad to know about that.

EDIT:
ok so i'm trying to use the mysqlcommandbuilder.
My code now looks like this:

```
                MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * from setups", sql_Class.myConnection);
            MySqlCommandBuilder cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(da);
            cb.GetUpdateCommand();

            da.Update(dt);
```

so now my error is in the da.Update(dt) and it says: "input string was not in the correct format".
I've created a loop that runs on all the parameters in the sql query and all the parameters values are null.

```
            for (int i = 0; i <= cb.GetUpdateCommand().Parameters.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(cb.GetUpdateCommand().Parameters[i].ParameterName + " " + cb.GetUpdateCommand().Parameters[i].Value);
            }
```

I have values in the datatable, i've double checked it, but someone the parameters are null.
Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to update my database in some "old fashion" method.

I'm just running on every single row in the datagridview and updates it using executenonquery.
I get all the parameters manually.

Example:
int setup_id = Convert.ToInt16(stam.Cells["setup_id"].Value);
string setup_name = stam.Cells["setup_name"].Value.ToString();
string mySqlQuery  = "UPDATE setups SET setup_name='"+setup_name+"' WHERE setup_id="+setup_id;

MySqlCommand cm = new MySqlCommand(mySqlQuery, sql_Class.myConnection);
cm.ExecuteNonQuery();